# Search issues with PHP and LDAP on Windows 2008

Tags: php, ldap, pear

I am trying to search through LDAP user entries on a Windows 2008 Server using PHP - PEAR's [Net_LDAP2](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_LDAP) package to be specific.  I have successfully connected to the server as well as bind a user; however, searching for a user results in LDAP_OPERATIONS_ERROR.  The most I can find as a solution on this is that it's hard to nail down a solution.

Is anyone familiar with connecting to LDAP via PHP on a Windows 2008 and would know the tweak that's need to access to the directory?

```
// LDAP Abstraction Layer with static instance of NET_LDAP2.
$LDAPConnection = new LDAPAbstractionLayer('username', 'password');
// Simple filter
$filter = Net_LDAP2_Filter::create('sn', 'begins',  'S');
$searchbase = 'DC=example,DC=domain';
$options = array('scope' => 'sub', 'attributes' => array('sn'));
$search = $LDAPConnection->connection->search($searchbase, $filter, $options);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you successfully bound to the LDAP server? I don't know much about Active Directory, but in OpenLDAP you can anonymously bind to an LDAP server, and if configured so, you can make searches but you'll require stronger authentication to have write access.

So the bottomline is: If you're anonymously bound to the server (because authentication with user/password failed), can you do anonymous searches?